# What does "in blue" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> You were, after all, brothers in blue

From TV Series *Elementary* S03E08, what does `in blue` mean here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without having seen the episode I can't answer definitively. Typically "in blue", or "blue" refers to Police, as in "thin blue line". Thus "brothers in blue" would mean members of the police force, which is often regarded as an informal fraternity. The association with "blue" is due to the perception that police traditionally wear blue, though many departments wear grey, black, brown, khaki or green. Comparable to the term "Green Machine" when referring to the USMC.

Comment: *Elementary* is a TV series about a current-day Sherlock Holmes and his partner (Watson, naturally) who assist the police in solving crimes.

Comment: I'm familiar with the show, I just don't watch it. I can't say  with certainty without seeing the episode that the speaker wasn't making an oblique reference to the Navy, Cavalry, Union Troops, or some other group that traditionally wore blue.

Comment: I haven't watched it, but I did find the dialog this is from and judging from the context, Sherlock was indeed talking about cops. Matter of fact, the next line of dialog is "Perhaps you no longer saw him as a real cop."

Comment: Well that's settled them. It's not in the comment, so I gotta go with what's there, in general anyway.